# Reference for Penrose-Ward transformation

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, twistor-theory

I am currently looking for a reference that covers the Penrose-Ward transformation. For context the Penrose-Ward transformation relates a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on some twistor space $Z$, with Kodaira moduli space $M$, to a holomorphic vector bundle with holomorphic connection on $M$ provided the bundle $E$ is $M$-trivial. At the moment one of my references for this is "[The generalized Penrose-Ward transform](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1985MPCPS..97..165E/abstract)" by M. Eastwood. And the other is "[Gauge Field Theory and Complex Geometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540613787)" by Y. Manin.

I am interested in a reference that is more detailed than "The generalized Penrose-Ward transform" and also a reference that covers the Penrose-Ward transformation in the case where the vector bundle $E\to M$ comes from an instanton. The second point is only commented on in "Gauge Field Theory and Complex Geometry" after Theorem 11 in Chapter 2 §2.

To summarize, I am looking for a detailed introduction to the Penrose-Ward transform that explains how to recover the self-dual connection from the holomorphic connection.